# "Unable to acquire application service" error while launching Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

When ever I try to launch my eclipse I am getting the following exception an its not coming up.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to acquire application service. Ensure that the org.eclipse.core.runtime bundle is resolved and started (see config.ini).                                                                         
  at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:74)
  at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:368)
  at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:559)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:514)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1311)
```

Need help.
Thanks.

Comment: In Arch Linux , this happens when you only install eclipse-common package, you must install eclipse-java or eclipse-cpp packages as well

Comment: @avances123, Thanks I was really confused. I installed eclipse from Software store :)

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The `/configuration/config.ini` file should contain `org.eclipse.core.runtime@start` in the commaseparated `osgi.bundles` property. Here is the default `osgi.bundles` property, maybe it was (accidently) changed during some upgrade:

```
osgi.bundles=org.eclipse.equinox.common@2:start,org.eclipse.update.configurator@3:start,org.eclipse.core.runtime@start
```

You can if necessary override it by setting it as VM argument in `/eclipse.ini`:

```
-Dosgi.bundles=org.eclipse.equinox.common@2:start,org.eclipse.update.configurator@3:start,org.eclipse.core.runtime@start
```

Comment: i am not able to find the config.ini file in my eclipse directory.

Comment: Since you accepted the answer 5 minutes later, may I assume that you finally found and fixed it?

Comment: the file is in the root of your Eclipse installation

Comment: I have osgi.bundle set my configuration I can not still start my eclipse

Comment: @Ashish: based on edit history, it appears that someone else malformed the needed line during an edit action. Chris Knight has fixed it. Sorry for any inconvenience caused by this, it is never my intent to post broken answers, this bad edit has simply slipped through my attention.

Comment: In **Mars**, what you can do is go to the **Product Configuration file** (open with the product conf editor), go to the **Configuration tab**, and under **Start Levels** simply click the **"Add Recommended..."** button. This fixed it for me. Cf. [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/mE3LpCl.png).

Comment: I cannot find any `osgi.bundles` in my `eclipse.ini` file. Should I add it myself?

Comment: I see "Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui;" in error log. Problem still exist, even with this solution.

Comment: should we restart eclipse after this ?

Comment: if you face this in 2021 or later better check that you have jdk 11 installed and is configured correctly. I downloaded latest eclipse-jee-2021-06-R-win32-x86_64 and on running i got this issue. I checked the java version on my system and it was:  1.8 I downloaded latest OpenJDK 11 configured it  (JAVA_HOME in environment variable and 
 <JAVAHOME/bin  entry in PATH environment varaible>) and the issue is gone.

Answer (score 15):

I have had the same problem, and here's how I solved it: I added the plugin "org.eclipse.core.runtime" in the "plugins" section on the "configuration" tab of the .product editor. I set it's start level to default and auto-start to true. I removed other plugins. My reasoning was this: Eclipse is complaining that the org.eclipse.core.runtime isn't started, so let's make sure that it does start, and that it's the only plugin that's starting.

My application ran fine after I did this. I then inspected the config.ini to see what changed, and saw that org.eclipse.core.runtime was now changed to org.eclipse.core.runtime@start. This is consistent with BalusC's suggestion, I just did it from the .product editor.

Answer (score 14):

Adding my two cents for those searching for "**Ensure that the org.eclipse.core.runtime bundle is resolved and started**":

Adding "arbitrary" bundles to the list of bundles just *because it seems that they are missing* is not always the best solution. Sometimes it can get quite frustrating, because those new plugins might depend on other missing bundles, which need even more bundles and so on...

So, before adding a new dependency to the list of required bundles, make sure you understand why the bundle is needed (the debugger is your friend!).

This question here doesn't provide enough information to make this a valid answer in all cases, but if you encounter the message that the *org.eclipse.core.runtime is missing*, try setting the **eclipse.application.launchDefault** system property to **false**, especially if you try to run an application which is not an "eclipse application" (but maybe just a headless runtime on top of equinox).

This link might come in handy: http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fmisc%2Fruntime-options.html, look for the eclipse.application.launchDefault system property.

Comment: +1 This is a very important piece.  The path to things is highly relevant in this situation.

Comment: Similarly, setting "osgi.noShutdown" to true will eliminate this error. I don't know if this is a new property that has been added since this answer but it aligns itself with evandor's explanation of what to do when not running and "eclipse application".

Answer (score 10):

try running it from the Command Line as:

```
 >eclipse -clean
```

Or, you could run it using `java` instead of the default `javaw`, here:

```
 >eclipse -vm c:\jdks\java_1.5\jre\bin\java.exe
```

Answer (score 6):

The accepted answer above is correct, except for it's not completely clear.

You need to add the following line to the bottom of the eclipse.ini file:

```
-Dosgi.bundles=org.eclipse.equinox.common@2:start,org.eclipse.update.configurator@3:start,org.eclipse.core.runtime@
```

Comment: Please use the *Post answer* button only if you have an answer of your own. If you want to correct another answer, use the "edit" link on that answer to edit it.

Comment: I think back then I didn't have permissions to edit an answer.

Answer (score 6):

I got this problem with Mac OS Lion, after transfer OS/Data from an older machine to a new one.

Solved deleting the old eclipse folder (which I have in Applications folder) and copy eclipse folder again (same version, same unpacked zip file, no changes).

Comment: On a related note, if you need to find an archive for a non-current version of Eclipse, they are here: http://archive.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/

Answer (score 4):

This error happen cause you deleted the config.ini file while you deleted the plugins.  So, when it can not find configuration in config.ini when eclipse lauching， then it use default  configuration which is not fit with your os. The following steps solve you problem:

1. Delete setting in configuration folder.
2. create a new config.ini file.
3. copy following setting and save:
4. ```
   osgi.splashPath = platform:/base/plugins/org.eclipse.platform  
   osgi.bundles=org.eclipse.equinox.common@2:start, org.eclipse.update.configurator@3:start, org.eclipse.core.runtime@start  
   eclipse.product=org.eclipse.sdk.ide  
   osgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/workspace  
   eof=eof
   ```
5. restart eclipse.

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: No application id has been found.
 at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppContainer.startDefaultApp(EclipseAppContainer.java:242)

Comment: This pointed me in the right direction. I needed to point the `-configuration` to `config_mac/` (and not run a standalone lsp process!).

Answer (score 4):

For me installing the `jdk 1.8` solved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

For me, what eventually did the trick was adding `-clean` at the start of eclipse.ini

Answer (score 1):

In the Windows environment, running Eclipse as Administrator solved the issue. (Right click>Run as Administrator)

Answer (score 1):

if you face this in 2021 or later better check that you have jdk 11 installed and is configured correctly. I downloaded the latest eclipse-jee-2021-06-R-win32-x86_64 and on running i got this issue. I checked the java version on my system and it was: 1.8 I downloaded the latest OpenJDK 11 configured it (JAVA_HOME in an environment variable and <JAVAHOME/bin entry in PATH environment varaible>) and the issue is gone.

Answer (score 0):

I've been downloaded the "SDK ADT Bundle for Windows" adt-bundle-windows-x86.zip to "Documents and settings\myusername\My Documents\Downloads"  and tried to unzip to a folder c:\Android

When all seems to be decompressed I saw some files where missing in the destination folder including the eclipse.ini.

I solved this by renaming `adt-bundle-windows-x86.zip` to a short name `adt.zip`, moving it to c:\ and repeating the decompression.

All is due to bad treatment of long file-names in windows

Comment: what does android have to do with the original question?

Answer (score 0):

For those coming here having tried to run the application from a Windows command line, or batch file, and possibly those receiving the stated error message in a Rational Clear Case log file:

The PATH is very important to the processing of config files, and the following was required for me:

```
START "Clear Case" /D"C:\Program Files (x86)\Rational\ClearQuest\rcp\" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Rational\ClearQuest\rcp\clearquest.exe"
```

note the **/D** option.

Comment: ClearQuest? How related to an eclipse problem?

Comment: @SamGinrich it has been a long time, but two thoughts. First the "command line, or batch file" comment was the main application. Second the plugins or possibly the built-in(?) integration with Eclipse was causing it to fail for me.  That said, I'd accept a downvote understandable.

Comment: Thank you. I came here while trying to move the hidden eclipse folders from the user home dfirectory to some other location - eclipse is a mess here!

Answer (score 0):

Adding to a well-populated page:

I had this come up when I tried to move the eclipse installation to a different location on my drive.  I tried grepping for the old directory path in the package, thinking perhaps I could fix it with sed, but the path was written in multiple formats and even found in binary files.  I gave up, made a fresh install, and re-installed my plugins.

(Here's a [question about moving an eclipse installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11554381/moving-eclipse-installation-directory-causes-problems), but it didn't give me enough to make it work.)

Answer (score 0):

shawn: My eclipse have started when I extended bundles:

```
osgi.bundles=org.eclipse.equinox.common@2:start, org.eclipse.update.configurator@3:start, org.eclipse.core.runtime@start, org.eclipse.equinox.ds@start, org.eclipse.equinox.event@start
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the methods proposed here. I finally deleted the eclipse folder, extracted it again and now everything works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I received this message trying to run STS 3.7.0 on java 6 jdk, after pointing to java jdk 7 (-vm param in STS.ini) the issue disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem somewhere on the logs and I saw that my java version was not 1.8 somehow. Upgrading it again to 1.8 solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Download new eclipse or spring suite and open old workspace into new eclipse or STS

Answer (score 0):

If none of the above answers works for you, try the following:
Get the "org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator" and the "org.eclipse.update" folders found under the "eclipse\configuration" from a working Eclipse instance (can be the stock Eclipse downloaded from their website) and replace them in your Eclipse installation directory.
This fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the answers above, but none of them worked for me, so I was forced to try something else. I just removed the whole package with settings org.eclipse.Java and it worked fine, starts again like before and even keeps all settings like color themes and others. Worked like charm.

On Linux or Mac go to /home/{your_user_name}/.var/app and run the following command:

```
 rm -r org.eclipse.Java
```

On Windows just find the same directory and move it to Trash.

After this is done, the settings and the errors are deleted, so Eclipse will start and re-create them with the proper settings.

When Eclipse starts it will ask for the workspace directory. When specified, everything works like before.

Comment: this folder appears in a fresh installation!?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that worked for me was to run Eclipse using JAVA from the command line.

```
C:\Development_Tools\eclipse\java-2021-092\eclipse>java -jar plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.6.300.v20210813-1054.jar
```

This was executed from the folder where eclipse.exe resides.

I made my own shortcut for this and now use that shortcut instead of the one produced when installing Eclipse from their website.

Answer (score -2):

in my opinion, if after trying all solution nothing wors then simply delete eclipse folder from your C://use/{pc}/eclipse and then again install the same eclipse . You will get all your data no need to worry.

This happens because of unexpected shutdown of your eclipse

Answer (score -3):

delete processcenter.ini at location similar to:
C:\IBM\IntegrationDesigner\v8.5\iid
and then once IDE comes up, go to windows preference and put in the correct URL.

Comment: The author doesn't mention Windows or any IBM flavour of Eclipse. What would the 'correct URL' look like?