# An error has occurred ,See the log file Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I am getting a following error while launching my eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493415/i-am-getting-a-following-error-while-launching-my-eclipse)

Recently an eclipse with ADT plugin for android is not running without any cause. While i try to run it, it is saying error has occurred , see the log file. I searched couple of things but could not find any solution. How can i proceed ahead ?

This is my log file of eclipse.

```
SESSION 2012-04-26 12:45:00.093 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.6.0_22
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -clean

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2012-04-26 12:45:00.765
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to acquire application service. Ensure that the       org.eclipse.core.runtime bundle is resolved and started (see config.ini).
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)`enter code here`
```

Comment: @THelper i check all the solutions for it over this at previous time but no one suits with this .. & gives the satisfied solution.

Comment: Is this the only error you get when you restart Eclipse? What version of Eclipse? Have you rebooted your machine and tried to restart Eclipse? Also, have you tried to download the latest version? Get the latest version and unzip it in your home dir and try to run it. Your error above will prevent you from even getting to the point of being able to upgrade or fix the problem package from within Eclipse.. So your best bet is to upgrade manually and reinstall ADT

Comment: i m using eclipse indigo 3.6.0 . Yes i had rebooted also but it's not working . Re installation is ok but if i could get the solution without  reinstallation means , it would be better. Thanks.. for help.