# Eclipse not starting after migration to new mac

Tags: eclipse, macos, migration

I just used the Migration Assistant to move my stuff to a new mac and now when I launch Eclipse, I'm getting a pop-up telling me to look at:

```
~/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_3.7.0_564163029/configuration/1343925478439.log
```

which contains:

```
!SESSION 2012-08-02 12:37:58.263 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.6.0_33
java.vendor=Apple Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=macosx, ARCH=x86_64, WS=cocoa, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product -keyring /Users/Me/.eclipse_keyring -showlocation
Command-line arguments:  -os macosx -ws cocoa -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product -keyring /Users/Me/.eclipse_keyring -showlocation

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2012-08-02 12:37:58.630
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to acquire application service. Ensure that the org.eclipse.core.runtime bundle is resolved and started (see config.ini).
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:74)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
```

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493415/i-am-getting-a-following-error-while-launching-my-eclipse): and tried adding the following to /Applications/eclipse-indigo/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipse.ini:

```
-Dosgi.bundles=org.eclipse.equinox.common@2:start,org.eclipse.update.configurator@3:start,org.eclipse.core.runtime@
```

but it still didn't work. I also tried running eclipse from the command line with the -clean option:

```
/Applications/eclipse-indigo/eclipse -clean
```

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what the error is, but since installing Eclipse is a simple matter of extracting the archive, I never try to migrate an Eclipse installation to a new machine. I just copy my workspace(s) over, install Eclipse fresh, and run.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue (eclipse helios), I compared my old system to the new one and for some reason the /Application/eclipse/configuration folder was very different

the new machine only had org.eclipse.osgi in the configuration folder, where as the old one had org.eclipse.core.runtime, org.eclipse.core.simpleconfigurator, org.eclipse.core.source, org.eclipse.osgi,org.eclipse.ui.intro.universal,org.eclipse.core.update.

I replace the new configuration folder with the old one and it started it up. It still wasn't the same though... a couple of things that I noticed was the eclipse marketplace was gone as well as all my maven builds.

Finally I just copied and the Application/eclipse folder from the old rig to the new one and it worked just fine.

Comment: To summarise: Just copy the eclipse folder from Applications from the source computer to the target.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the old mac and find the Eclipse folder under /Applications. Then copy the "configuration" folder to the new Mac and replace the corrupt configuration folder at the same path, also in /Applications/eclipse. This happens because OS X Migration Assistant mistakenly thinks the configuration files are an application incompatible with your new computer.