# unable to start eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I am getting following error while starting eclipse

```
!SESSION 2013-01-26 16:03:57.125 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=M20120208-0800
java.fullversion=JRE 1.6.0 IBM J9 2.4 Windows XP x86-32 jvmwi3260sr9-20110726_87724 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)
J9VM - 20110726_087724
JIT  - r9_20101028_17488ifx17
GC   - 20101027_AA
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product com.ibm.rational.rsa4ws.product.v80.ide
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -product com.ibm.rational.rsa4ws.product.v80.ide -clean -consoleLog

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2013-01-26 16:04:17.812
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to acquire application service. Ensure that the org.eclipse.core.runtime bundle is resolved and started (see config.ini).
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Look once http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493415/i-am-getting-a-following-error-while-launching-my-eclipse

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need to add the following code to the bottom of eclipse.ini:

```
     Dosgi.bundles=org.eclipse.equinox.common@2:start,org.eclipse.update.configurator@3:start,org.e.  clipse.core.runtime@
```

If it still doesn't work then it looks like your going to have to re-install eclipse. I assume you know how to do so. One common mistake is downloading the wrong 'bit' package. Say if your PC is 32 bit but you download a 64 bit package.

Comment: I have already done that. But it is not working and I seriously do not want to re-install everything

Comment: Why don't you want to re-install? Just backup all your projects on somewhere like Dropbox or a USB.

Comment: The reason I do not want to re-install is that I have to re-install rational clear case as well which is the plug-in for the rational software architect and I am afraid I will loose some data