# java.lang.IllegalStateException when clicking on Android Device Monitor

Tags: java, android, android-studio

After launching Android studio and clicking on Android Device Monitor icon there is an error log.
Output of this log is that:

```
!SESSION 2015-08-25 09:32:26.463 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.7.0_79
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2015-08-25 09:32:27.209
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to acquire application service. Ensure that the org.eclipse.core.runtime bundle is resolved and started (see config.ini).
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
```

How can I resolve this problem ?

Comment: r u able to see device connected ?

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493415/unable-to-acquire-application-service-error-while-launching-eclipse

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493415/unable-to-acquire-application-service-error-while-launching-eclipse

Comment: @RajeshJadav @sasikumar I haven\`t `config.ini` in `configuration` folder. Others answers didn\`t help me. And how I understood, there was about eclipse not android studio

Comment: Update: adding bundles to `config.ini` doesn`t help me