# I can't start Eclipse. ErrorMsg: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to acquire application service

Tags: java, eclipse

The folder of Eclipse files is on my desktop.

I'm learning git these days, so I used SourceTree to create a new repository on my Desktop.

Then, I deleted the repository from disk (commit nothing), and most of the files on my desktop were gone.

Thus, I can't start Eclipse.

The Eclipse folder is still there, but I'm not sure if something is missing or  moved.

I don't know where the problem is, either.

Here's the error message:

[After clicking eclipse icon:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWODT.png)

**logFile:**

> !SESSION 2016-01-13 17:27:38.509
>   ----------------------------------------------- eclipse.buildId=unknown java.version=1.7.0_71 java.vendor=Oracle
>   Corporation BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32,
>   NL=zh_TW Framework arguments:  -product
>   org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product Command-line arguments:  -os win32
>   -ws win32 -arch x86 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2016-01-13 17:27:38.867 !MESSAGE
>   Application error !STACK 1 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to
>   acquire application service. Ensure that the org.eclipse.core.runtime
>   bundle is resolved and started (see config.ini).  at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:78)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)  at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Unable to acquire application service" error while launching Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493415/unable-to-acquire-application-service-error-while-launching-eclipse)

Comment: You could try to start eclipse with the option `-clean`, eg.: `eclipse.exe -clean`

Comment: @Adam Kortylewicz I tried, but it dosen't workk .

Comment: @mnille  it shows the errorMsg like the picture I post.

Comment: Just download and install new eclipse in the new directory I think it will help

Comment: check your java version in eclipse and jre u have selected. and make sure that you have downloaded the correct version of eclipse(if your system is 32 bit download 32 bit, if 64 bit then download 64 bit eclipse)

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493415/unable-to-acquire-application-service-error-while-launching-eclipse) solution?

Comment: @Nirmal Dhara    The version I checked is right.

Comment: @ Igorovics  yes,I tried.

Comment: @ Tito   I know, but that's a way i don't want to choose.  Because it will spend much time to build the environment I used .

Comment: Finally, I  install new eclipse .  Thank you everybody.