# Eclipse Plugin Project Run Configurations

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins

Does anyone know how can I fix this problem?

I am doing a plug-in project with GEF.
I have created a new Eclipse Application when I selected Run As>Run Configurations...>Eclipse Application>New launch configuration. Then at the Main tab I put this Location: ${workspace_loc}/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.pde.core/runtime-New_configuration.
In my xml-file I described my application:

```
   <extension
         id="application"
         point="org.eclipse.core.runtime.applications">
      <application>
         <run
               class="tutogef.Application">
         </run>
      </application>
```

When I execute the plugin it shows the message below:

```
!SESSION 2016-12-09 16:26:41.951 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.8.0_111
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=de_DE
Framework arguments:  -application TutoGEF.application
Command-line arguments:  -application TutoGEF.application -data /home/jacque/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.pde.core/runtime-New_configuration -dev file:/home/jacque/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.pde.core/New_configuration/dev.properties -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -consoleLog

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 2 10035 2016-12-09 16:26:50.800
!MESSAGE The workspace exited with unsaved changes in the previous session; refreshing workspace to recover changes.
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [bundleresource://1035.fwk655381473:1/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [bundleresource://1035.fwk655381473:2/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextSelectorStaticBinder]

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui.workbench 4 2 2016-12-09 16:26:56.608
!MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.ui.workbench".
!STACK 0
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.ui.SetupUIPlugin.performStartup(SetupUIPlugin.java:189)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.ui.EarlyStartup.earlyStartup(EarlyStartup.java:22)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.runEarlyStartup(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:77)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.run(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$55.run(Workbench.java:2829)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.util.SetupUtil.<clinit>(SetupUtil.java:35)
    ... 7 more

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2016-12-09 16:26:56.613
!MESSAGE Unable to execute early startup code for the org.eclipse.ui.IStartup extension contributed by the 'org.eclipse.oomph.setup.ui' plug-in.
!STACK 0
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.ui.SetupUIPlugin.performStartup(SetupUIPlugin.java:189)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.ui.EarlyStartup.earlyStartup(EarlyStartup.java:22)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.runEarlyStartup(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:77)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.run(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$55.run(Workbench.java:2829)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.util.SetupUtil.<clinit>(SetupUtil.java:35)
    ... 7 more
```

I don't have idea where I am doing something wrong...

Answer (score 0):

**

> *The easiest way just reinstall your eclipse program it will work again as usual. Its a best way if gonna search answers you will waste
>   your time peace. ;)*

**
This link for your problem.
[GO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493415/unable-to-acquire-application-service-error-while-launching-eclipse#answers-header)