# android device monitor, an error has occured, see the log file

Tags: android

I can't open Android Device Monitor in android studio.

Tools > Android > Android Device Monitor.

I meet this error message.

[image]

```
> !SESSION 2017-11-12 21:54:09.305
> ----------------------------------------------- eclipse.buildId=unknown java.version=9.0.1 java.vendor=Oracle
> Corporation BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32,
> NL=ko_KR Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64
> -data @noDefault
> 
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-11-12 21:54:10.284 !MESSAGE Bundle
> reference:file:org.apache.ant_1.8.3.v201301120609/@4 not found.
> 
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-11-12 21:54:10.299 !MESSAGE Bundle
> reference:file:org.apache.jasper.glassfish_2.2.2.v201205150955.jar@4
> not found.
> 
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-11-12 21:54:10.303 !MESSAGE Bundle
> reference:file:org.apache.lucene.core_2.9.1.v201101211721.jar@4 not
> found.
> 
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-11-12 21:54:10.492 !MESSAGE Bundle
> reference:file:org.eclipse.help.base_3.6.101.v201302041200.jar@4 not
> found.
> 
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-11-12 21:54:10.493 !MESSAGE Bundle
> reference:file:org.eclipse.help.ui_3.5.201.v20130108-092756.jar@4 not
> found.
> 
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-11-12 21:54:10.494 !MESSAGE Bundle
> reference:file:org.eclipse.help.webapp_3.6.101.v20130116-182509.jar@4
> not found.
> 
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-11-12 21:54:10.499 !MESSAGE Bundle
> reference:file:org.eclipse.jetty.server_8.1.3.v20120522.jar@4 not
> found.
> 
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-11-12 21:54:10.515 !MESSAGE Bundle
> reference:file:org.eclipse.platform.doc.user_4.2.2.v20130121-200410.jar@4
> not found.
> 
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-11-12 21:54:10.521 !MESSAGE Bundle
> reference:file:org.eclipse.team.core_3.6.100.v20120524-0627.jar@4 not
> found.
> 
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-11-12 21:54:10.522 !MESSAGE Bundle
> reference:file:org.eclipse.team.ui_3.6.201.v20130125-135424.jar@4 not
> found.
> 
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-11-12 21:54:10.527 !MESSAGE Bundle
> reference:file:org.eclipse.ui.cheatsheets_3.4.200.v20120521-2344.jar@4
> not found.
> 
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-11-12 21:54:10.536 !MESSAGE Bundle
> reference:file:org.eclipse.ui.intro_3.4.200.v20120521-2344.jar@4 not
> found.
> 
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.core.runtime 4 0 2017-11-12 21:54:10.644 !MESSAGE
> FrameworkEvent ERROR !STACK 0 org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The
> bundle "org.eclipse.core.runtime_3.8.0.v20120912-155025 [46]" could
> not be resolved. Reason: Missing Constraint:
> Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: CDC-1.0/Foundation-1.0,J2SE-1.3
>   at
> org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.getResolverError(AbstractBundle.java:1332)
>   at
> org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.getResolutionFailureException(AbstractBundle.java:1316)
>   at
> org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:323)
>   at
> org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:390)
>   at
> org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1176)
>   at
> org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
>   at
> org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
>   at
> org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
>   at
> org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
>   at
> org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
>   at
> org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
>   at
> org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
>   at
> org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
> 
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.common 4 0 2017-11-12 21:54:10.647 !MESSAGE
> FrameworkEvent ERROR !STACK 0 org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The
> bundle "org.eclipse.equinox.common_3.6.100.v20120522-1841 [84]" could
> not be resolved. Reason: Missing Constraint:
> Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: CDC-
> 
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-11-12 21:54:10.714 !MESSAGE Could not
> start bundle: org.eclipse.equinox.console !STACK 0
> org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not start bundle:
> org.eclipse.equinox.console   at 
> 
> ... ellipsis ...
> 
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-11-12 21:54:10.897 !MESSAGE
> Application error !STACK 1 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to
> acquire application service. Ensure that the org.eclipse.core.runtime
> bundle is resolved and started (see config.ini).  at
> org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:74)
>   at
> org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
>   at
> org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
>   at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method)   at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown
> Source)   at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown
> Source)   at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
>   at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)    at
> org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)     at
> org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
```

I have already tried the following:

1. Reinstall android studio
2. Update Java version & fix environment variable
3. Run android studio & monitor.bat as administer mode
4. Uncheck read-only option for various directory

But nothing works..

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Unable to acquire application service" error while launching Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493415/unable-to-acquire-application-service-error-while-launching-eclipse)

Answer (score 0):

Try to open Android Studio in Administrative mode (https://www.digitalcitizen.life/how-run-programs-administrator-windows-7) **OR**
Kill *monitior.exe* from Task Manager.