# Android Device Monitor cant open on Windows 10

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am running a 64bit windows 10 and have the latest AndroidStudio3.0 and when try to open Android Device Monitor through Android Studio or command prompt both as admin I keep getting this error log:

[image: Error log]

and the log file contains

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2018-01-22 09:36:11.938 
!MESSAGEApplication error 
!STACK 1 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to
 acquire application service. Ensure that the org.eclipse.core.runtime
 bundle is resolved and started (see config.ini).   at
 org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:74)
    at
 org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at
 org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at
 java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
 Method)    at
 java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown
 Source)    at
 java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown
 Source)    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)    at
 org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)  at
 org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
```

and all the other Fixes that I've seen online have not worked for me.

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493415/unable-to-acquire-application-service-error-while-launching-eclipse

Comment: I have tried this solution and either I'm not implementing it right or it's not working for me.